# A can beat B 5 m in a 100 m race and B can beat C by 10 m in a 200 m race. Then in a race if 500 m,what is the lead that A can give C?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A can beat B 5 m in a 100 m race and B can beat C by 10 m in a 200 m race. Then in a race if 500 m,what is the lead that A can give C?

In 100 m race,
A covered 100 m and B 90 m
When A would have covered 1 m then B would have covered $90/100$
When A would have covered 500 m then B would have covered $90/100*500$=450 m

In 200 m race,
When B would have covered 1 m then c would have covered $190/200$
When B would have covered 500 m then C would have covered $190/200*500$=475 m
Now how to calculate the lead part?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_A$ be the speed of $A$ and similarly for the others.

The time taken for $A$ to run $100$ m is $\frac{100}{v_A}$ and this is the same time for $B$ to run $95$ m. Therefore $$\frac{95}{v_B}=\frac{100}{v_A}\implies v_B=\frac{95}{100}v_A$$

Similarly, $$v_C=\frac{190}{200}v_B=\frac{190\times95}{200\times100}v_A$$

The time taken for $A$ to run $500$ m is $\frac{500}{v_A}$, and in this time, $C$ runs a distance $500-x$ where $x$ is the winning margin. Therefore, $$\frac{500}{v_A}=\frac {500-x}{v_C}$$

Solving these, we get $$x=500-500\times\frac{190\times95}{200\times100}=\color{red}{48.75}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the rule of three (proportion) :

1) A runs 100,  while B runs 95.

2) B runs 200,  while C runs 190.

Consider a race of 500.

A runs 500, while B runs 475.

2') B runs 25, while C runs 190/8.

B runs 19×25 = 475, while C runs 19×190/8

Finally A runs 500, while B runs 475, while C runs 19×190/8.

A  leads C by:  500 - 19×190/8 = 48.75